# QTreeView, QTableView, display items of different hierarchy layers

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt

I want to display data using one custom Model (inherited from QAbstractItemModel), in a QTableView and a QTreeView.

My question is, is it possible to display all elements (i mean ALL elements, not just those from one hierarchy level) of the Model in the QTableView? So far i only managed to display items of one hierarchy level in a QTable View.

```
QTreeView:
-A
  -A1
  -A2
-B
  -B1
  -B2

QTableView // current behaviour
-A
-B

QTableView // desired behaviour
-A
-A1
-A2
-B
-B1
-B2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do here is use a proxy model to flatten the tree model before it got to the QTableView. Basically, it's a model that sits in front of your main model and serves it in a different format if the situation calls for it, but without affecting the model itself. You can read about how to do this with Qt [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#proxy-models).

[image: proxy model]

Comment: +1 Qt's document must include a Similar diagram to give better representation of the idea.